# Customizing a Pure CSS Responsive Menu With Multiple Conditions

Tags: css, menu, responsive

I'm working on this responsive menu using the code from here:

**http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/03/multi-level-responsive-dropdown-menu.html**

I am attempting to modify the code so that it satisfies all the following conditions:

1. It does not display a background color on any of the top buttons.
2. It always has black text in the sub menus.
3. All sub menus behave exactly the same in the responsive design.

But, I am running into several problems. One of which: two items in the main menu appear twice in the responsive submenu and I don't know why.

I have tried multiple solutions including:

1. Using additional CSS class selectors.
2. Every variation of colors in the existing CSS that I can think of.
3. Every variation of additional CSS class selectors I can think of.

I am very much looking forward to seeing this project fully completed and off my plate. If you could please take a look and identify where I'm going wrong on this code, I would be forever grateful. Thank you so very much.

```css
body {
 background-color: #908888;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}
menu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #5E4C4C;
}
menu:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
menu ul {
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}
menu ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px 20px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 17px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
menu a.new {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px 20px;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 17px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
menu a.new2 {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px 20px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 17px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #5E4C4C;
}
menu ul li ul li:hover {
 background-color: #f6f4fd;
 color: #000000;
}
menu a:hover {
 background-color: none;
 color: #fff;
}
menu a.new:hover {
 background-color: #f6f4fd;
 color: #000000;
}
menu a.new2:hover {
 background-color: #5E4C4C;
 color: #ffffff;
}
menu ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 48px;
}
menu ul li:hover > ul {
 color: #000000;
 display: inherit;
}
menu ul ul li {
 width: 170px;
 float: none;
 display: list-item;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 0px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #000000;
}
menu ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top: -60px;
 left: 170px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #000000;
}
li > a:after {
 content: ' ▼';
 font-size: 11px;
}
li > a:only-child:after {
 content: '';
}

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
 menu {
  margin: 0;
 }
 .toggle + a,  .menu {
  display: none;
 }
 .toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #5E4C4C;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
 }
 .toggle:hover {
  background-color: #DC4E5B;
 }
 [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
 }
 menu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }
 menu ul ul .toggle,  menu ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
 }
 menu ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
 }
 menu a:hover,  menu ul ul ul a {
  background-color: #f6f4fd;
 }
 menu a.new:hover {
  background-color: #f6f4fd;
  color: #000000;
 }
 menu a.new2:hover {
  background-color: #5E4C4C;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 menu ul li ul li .toggle,  menu ul ul a,  menu ul ul ul a {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 17px;
 }
 menu ul li ul li .toggle,  menu ul ul a {
  background-color: #BF3441;
 }
 menu ul ul {
  float: none;
  position: static;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 menu ul ul li:hover > ul,  menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: none;
 }
 menu ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }
 menu ul ul ul li {
  position: static;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
 menu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 94%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Multilevel Responsive Menu using css</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<menu>
    <label for="drop" class="toggle" style="background-color: #BC7A1E;">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="new2" href="#">My Bid</a></li>
        <li>
            <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Dashboard &#9660;</label>
            <a class="new2" href="#">Dashboard</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="new" href="#">Dashboard1</a></li>
                <li><a class="new" href="#">Dashboard2</a></li>
                <li><a class="new" href="#">Dashboard3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Identity &#9660;</label>
            <a class="new2" href="#">Identity</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="new" href="#">Identity1</a></li>
                <li><a class="new" href="#">Identity2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Identity3 &#9660;</label>
                    <a class="new" href="#">Identity3</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="new" href="#">Identity3.1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="new" href="#">Identity3.2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="new" href="#">Identity3.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Invalid Bid Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rft Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</menu>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twice menu problem is because you have media query it changing the display property of this `<label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Dashboard ▼</label>` tag .

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Anzil!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `menu a.new2 { display : block; }`. Its on line 58, i think. Remove only the `display: block` declaration, not the entire rule.

That should solve that duplicate link issue.